# Issue deleting parent of a one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF6 and am trying to delete a parent without including the children in the context request made prior to calling remove. I realize that this question has been asked a few times and I have tried to implement the various version of answers but I continue to get a foreign key constraint issue when deleting the parent without including the children in the context request.

Parent:

```
public class Weapon
{
    public Weapon()
    {
        Dices = new List<Dice>();
    }

    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public List<Dice> Dices { get; set; }
}
```

Child:

```
 public class Dice
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public int Sides { get; set; }
     public Guid WeaponId { get; set; }
     public Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
 }
```

Dice Mapping

```
// Relationships
 this.HasRequired(_ => _.Weapon)
 .WithMany(_ => _.Dices)
 .HasForeignKey(_ => _.WeaponId)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

If I get a weapon out of the context without including the Dice then the delete will fail due to foreign key constraint. However If I include the dice then the delete on weapon works with out a hitch. IE

Works:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteWeapon(Guid id)
{
    Weapon weapon = await _dbContext.Weapons.Include(w=>w.Dices).SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Id == id);
    _dbContext.Weapons.Remove(weapon);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

Fails:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteWeapon(Guid id)
{
    Weapon weapon = await _dbContext.Weapons.SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Id == id);
    _dbContext.Weapons.Remove(weapon);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

I would really prefer to not have to include all of the children of an object just to delete the parent, and I though that was what the WillCascadeOnDelete flag was for.

Comment: That's because there isn't a cascaded delete in the *database*, only in the EF model.

Comment: Anyway to add cascade to the database through code? (ie no sql scripts run)

Comment: How did you create the database? Code-first should have created the cascading delete foreign key constraint.

Comment: I create it time an time again with my code first mappings.

Answer (score 0):

In general, relational databases have built in constraints to not allow an entry which is the parent of a relationship to be deleted.  This is the database trying to prevent you from making a query down the line that will break it.

I'm not sure why you want to delete the row, but a common workaround is to simply add a `BOOLEAN` column to the table you are trying to delete from called `Active`. Instead of deleting the row itself simply mark the entry as `FALSE` and have your code that is referencing the Database make any necessary checks, or use more robust queries.

If you ABSOLUTELY need to delete the row, you need to break the appropriate relationships.  If you still want to save that relationship data you will need another table or something to store it in, at which point it becomes more complicated than the solution I gave above with the `Active` row.

Comment: This is not really an answer (I don't know how to do A => don't do A). But it's not a "common" work around either. You'll jump from the frying pan into the fire because you'll always have to query for `Active` records, which is particularly hard with EF when the records are in collection navigation properties.